# Using substring, locating specific data within a column and what to do next

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**(1) DDL and sample data population**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [First released] VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([First released]) VALUES
('2006-02-28NA'),
('2004PAL');
```

**(2) What I need to do, i.e. logic and code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL**

So I have two tables that I joined using UNION. I realized that one of my columns named `[first released]` has the date and which region released `2006-02-28NA`. I used the substring to eliminate those letters since I already have the JP region column, EU/PAL region, and NA region columns.

`Select Title, Developer, Publisher, SUBSTRING([First released],1,10) As [First released] , JP, [EU/PAL], NA`

The result is that some rows fit what I want `2006-10-06` and other rows that I need to update or eliminate `2004PAL`. With that being said how did I find this insufficient written data in the `First released` to see which ones I, how many I need to change, and how I update?

This is in order to make each row similar like `2006-10-06` and how to update it in the end

**(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.**

**(4) SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16-GDR) (KB5014353) - 15.0.4236.7 (X64)   May 29 2022 15:55:47   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I don't get this at all. I am sorry I am not understanding how to share a problem from Microsoft SQL and paste it here to look like a SQL code

Comment: Just copy ##1-4 to your question, and use them as section headers

Comment: So typing "##1-4 leads to what and how that help to solve my problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example is not provided.

Pease try the following conceptual example.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [First released] VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([First released]) VALUES
('2006-02-28NA'),
('2004PAL');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , real_date
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CAST(LEFT([First released], 10) AS DATE))) AS t1(real_date)
WHERE real_date IS NOT NULL; -- real dates
--WHERE real_date IS NULL; -- bogus dates
```

**Output**

| ID | First released | real_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2006-02-28NA | 2006-02-28 |